# No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"

Tags: python, html, windows, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to learn how to use Python to create PDFs from an HTML template (I'm very new at this).  My code is very simple:

```
import jinja2
import pdfkit
from datetime import datetime

path_wkthmltopdf = r"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
```

However, this returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PDF_HTML_Test_1\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 35, in __init__
    with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Wardrobe\Mess\basic_pdf.py", line 26, in <module>
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PDF_HTML_Test_1\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 86, in configuration
    return Configuration(**kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PDF_HTML_Test_1\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 38, in __init__
    raise IOError('No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "%s"\n'
OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it or you can pass path to it manually in method call, check README. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

As far as I can tell, the .exe file is in Program Files:

[image]

But for whatever reason, I keep getting an error message about the .exe file not being in
'/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf' despite the fact I told it to use a different file path. I've added the path to Environment Variables, but that didn't help anything.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and ran successfully on local win machine and aws ec2 linux machine:

```
import platform
os_platform = platform.system()
pdfkit_path = r"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
if os_platform == "Linux":
    pdfkit_path = "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
elif os_platform == "Darwin":
    pdfkit_path = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=pdfkit_path)
pdf = pdfkit.from_url(url, False, configuration=config)
```

Comment: Admittedly, I did end up getting it to work some months ago, but because I didn't post about it right then, I don't know what I did to fix it; this old code here in the post and the code in the script are essentially the same.  In the future I'll have to make a point to post a solution as soon as I stumble upon it.  Having the path be dependent on the platform does seem like a helpful trick to keep in mind for future problems though, thank you!